# Não consigo chamar a função

Tags: c#

Fiz esse código *quick sort* abaixo e não consigo chamar a função. Ate agora só fiz funções básicas e não consigo achar o erro.

```cs
public static void ordenar(int[] vetor)
{
    ordenar(vetor, 0, vetor.Length - 1);
}
public static void ordenar(int[] vetor, int inicio, int fim)
{
    if (inicio < fim)
    {
        int posisaoPivo=separa(vetor, inicio, fim);
        ordenar(vetor, inicio, posisaoPivo - 1);
        ordenar(vetor, posisaoPivo + 1, fim);
    }
}
private static int  separa(int[] vetor, int inicio, int fim)
{
    int pivo = vetor[inicio];
    int i = inicio + 1, f = fim;
    while (i <= f)
    {
        if (vetor[i] <= pivo)
            i++;
        else if (pivo < vetor[f])
            f--;
        else
        {
            int troca = vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = vetor[f];
            vetor[f] = troca;
            i++;
            f--;
        }
    }
    vetor[inicio] = vetor[f];
    vetor[f] = pivo;
    return f;
}
```

Programa principal:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int a=0, b=0,c=0;
            Console.WriteLine("digite os numeros");
            int[] numeros = new int[4];
           b=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           c=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                a = separa(numeros,b,c);

              numeros[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            }


            Console.WriteLine("numeros {0}=",separa(numeros, b, c).ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: O que acontece?

Comment: Olá. Que erro é que encontra? Que output é que estava a espera? Tenha ainda em atenção que `b=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` está errado. O `Console.ReadLine()` pode devolver um `null` o que causa uma `FormatException` no `int.Parse(...)`. O correcto será ler o input para uma variável, verificar que não é `null` e depois fazer o `int.Parse` (ou `int.TryParser(...)` que não devolve excepções mas sim uma flag a indicar se o parsing foi sucedido ou não.

Comment: A função de ordenar nem é chamada no código principal, além de outros probleminhas.

Comment: @Omni, ou usar `Nullable<Int32>`.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você esta tentando fazer é testar o algoritmo de ordenação, veja se o código abaixo te ajuda.

```
using System;


class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] vetor = new int[0];

            int index = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Didite o " + index + "° numero ou 'enter' para ordenar:");
                string entrada = Console.ReadLine();
                if (entrada == "")
                    break;

                int num = 0;
                if(int.TryParse(entrada, out num))
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref vetor, index);
                    vetor[index-1] = num;
                    index++;
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Vetor informado:");
            foreach (int i in vetor)
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + " ");
            }

            Ordenar(vetor);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Vetor ordenado:");
            foreach (int i in vetor)
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Pressione 'Enter' para sair.");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }



        public static void Ordenar(int[] vetor)
        {
            Ordenar(vetor, 0, vetor.Length - 1);
        }

        private static void Ordenar(int[] vetor, int inicio, int fim)
        {
            if (inicio < fim)
            {
                int posicaoPivo = Separar(vetor, inicio, fim);
                Ordenar(vetor, inicio, posicaoPivo - 1);
                Ordenar(vetor, posicaoPivo + 1, fim);
            }
        }

        private static int Separar(int[] vetor, int inicio, int fim)
        {
            int pivo = vetor[inicio];
            int i = inicio + 1, f = fim;
            while (i <= f)
            {
                if (vetor[i] <= pivo)
                    i++;
                else if (pivo < vetor[f])
                    f--;
                else
                {
                    int troca = vetor[i];
                    vetor[i] = vetor[f];
                    vetor[f] = troca;
                    i++;
                    f--;
                }
            }
            vetor[inicio] = vetor[f];
            vetor[f] = pivo;
            return f;
        }

    }
```